# Proof that $\Vert x \Vert_0 = \mathrm{supp}(x)$

Tags: linear-algebra

I was reading a book on compressive sensing wherein they mentioned that in the limit, the zeroth norm of a vector is the number of non-zero elements in that vector. That is,

$$\lim_{p\rightarrow 0} \Vert x\Vert _p = \Vert x\Vert_0 = |\mathrm{supp}(x)|$$

where $\mathrm{supp}(x)$ is the number of non-zero elements in $x$.

I could not prove this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true in this form.
If $k>0$ out of the $n$ components of $x$ are nonzero, let $c=\min\{\,|x_i|:1\le i\le n, x_i\ne 0\,\}$. Then $c>0$.
Also let $C=\max\{\,|x_i|:1\le i\le n\,\}$. 
Then 
$$k^{1/p}c=(kc^p)^{1/p}\le\|x\|_p=\left(\sum |x_i|^p\right)^{1/p}\le (kC^p)^{1/p}=k^{1/p}C $$
As $p\to 0$, both bounds tend to $+\infty$ if $k\ge2$ and for $k=1$ they reamin constant at $c$ and $C$, that is unrelated to $k$.

However, we see that
$$kc^p\le \|x\|_p^p\le kC^p $$
and here both bounds tend to $k$ as $p\to 0$.

Comment: But we do have $\lim_{p \to 0} \| x \|_p^p = \| x \|_0 = | \{ j: x_j \ne 0\} |$, right?